# Is Apache Camel route step scope always singleton?

Tags: apache-camel

I mean that if (for example) processor bean is declared in Blueprint XML and included into just one route, then its single instance is used by every thread that executes message routing within this route. So I guess that there is no sense in prototype scope for such bean declaration.
The only right place to use prototype scope for route step declaration is the case when bean is used in several routes. In this case there will be created separate instance of bean for every route.
Am I wright?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728029/apache-camel-pojo-bean-processor-singleton-or-prototype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No if you refer to the same bean id in multiple routes its the same instance you are using.

You can configure Camel bean component to turn off its cache with `cache=false` and define the bean to be prototype scoped to have a new instance per call - however its seldom used and also a bad practice. Its better to code your beans as thread-safe.

Comment: I know this is an old post Is it possible to create a bean per request which exist till the route ends @Claus